# Lotus Notes - get mail database of current user

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

Is there a way in Lotus Notes (using either @Formula or LotusScript) to get the mail file path of the current user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Dim maildb As New NotesDatabase("", "")
 Call maildb.OpenMail
```

gives you the [mail database of current user](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_OPENMAIL_METHOD.html).

`maildb.FilePath` returns the file path.

Comment: I have added Dim maildb As New NotesDatabase("", ""), Messagebox maildb.FilePath to a form action but the messagbox is empty. Have I missed something here?

Comment: Don't forget line `Call maildb.OpenMail`

Answer (score 4):

@MailDbName is the formula counterpart to the answer from Knut. It returns a text list with two elements: Server and path.

Comment: so @MailDbName[2] will return you the filepath. :-)